# A script for google spreadsheet to provide multiple hyperlink choice for one cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet.  In some cells, it has multiple names(strings) that I would like to associate with individual hyperlinks.

E.g. if I have a cell such as "Charles Darwin", it's easy for me to create a hyperlink out of this name by doing something like

```
=Hyperlink(VLOOKUP("Charles Darwin", People!$A$1:$B$738, 2, false), "Charles Darwin")
```

(note that I have a "People" sheet from which I grab the hyperlink)

But if I happen to have multiple entries in that cell, say ";" or newline separated, e.g., "Charles Darwin; George Washington", I can't do that.  I'd like to give the user an ability to click on the cell, have the contents of the cell be sent (as argument) to some kind of script, and for that script to find the hyperlinks in my "People" sheet for those strings, and then to present the user with a little "pop-up" right next to that cell, where the desired hyperlink could be clicked on.

I tried to find something along those lines on this site, but nothing similar seemed to come up.  Might someone have a link or two for me (or basic example code) that I could start with to try to solve this? (I am assuming this is possible).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61787891/1595451

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to have two hyperlinks on the same cell.

It is possible to write scripts to Google Spreadsheets, but I'm not sure it's going to suit your use case well. The solution I see would be like this:

- The user click on the desired cell, selecting it.
- Then he clicks on a custom menu and picks an entry there, e.g. show links
- A popup will show up (not besides the cell, but centered on the screen) with the links.

Do you think this is fine? The code would look like this (open the menu Tools > Script Editor)

```js
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().
    addMenu("Test", [{name: 'Show Links', functionName:'showLinks'}]);
}

function showLinks() {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValue().split(';');

  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Links'); 
  var grid = app.createGrid(values.length, 2);

  for( var i = 0; i < values.length; ++i ) {
    var url = findLink(values[i]);
    grid.setWidget(
      i, 0, app.createLabel(values[i])).setWidget(
      i, 1, url ? app.createAnchor(url, url) : app.createLabel('Not Found'));
  }

  app.add(grid);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().show(app);
}

var mapName2Url = null;
function findLink(name) {
  if( mapName2Url == null ) { //lazy load
    mapName2Url = {};
    var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('People').getDataRange().getValues();
    for( var i = 1; i < data.length; ++i ) //skipping the header
      mapName2Url[data[i][0]] = data[i][1];
  }
  return mapName2Url[name];
}
```

After you paste it on the script editor, run the onOpen function twice to authorize it and have the menu created for you. Next time you open the spreadsheet, the menu should be created automatically.

By the way, I have not tested this code, so it might contain dumb mistakes.

Comment: Hey, Henrique,  Thanks for your help.  This code works great - its logic is right, but I do need it to be not a menu item.  I intend for this spreadsheet to be shown in a website as "list view" (no menus).  What I guess I really need is for each cell that I want to work as "multiple hyperlink" to be itself a link to this script.  Perhaps I need to publish the script "as service"? (I don't really know the difference).  I also see that they have introduced the "exprimental" feature "build a user interface". p.s. for some reason "Test" menu only appeared once for me, and then disappeared.

Comment: forgot to add @ above, sorry.

Comment: You'll not be able to have one cell behave as "multiple hyperlink", that is just not possible, period. If you have the cells after it in your spreadsheet free, you could work on a `ArrayFormula` to have each cell in the row of the desired one to have each required link.

Comment: I know that it's impossible for "one cell to have multiple hyperlinks".  But I am wondering if it's possible to call this script by clicking on a link to the script in a cell, or something like that.  Is there a way to set up this script to make it possible?  It's the same idea as calling it from the Spreadsheet menu, but simply a different trigger.

Comment: Impossible too. Selecting a cell is not a "triggerable" event on Apps Script. And spreadsheets embedded on sites complicate things even more.

Comment: Well, damn. sucks.  Thanks for the code, still.  And I was completely convinced that there was a way to write custom functions and make it all work in a similar way that the built-in "Hyperlink" function works - has that little "pop out". I thought there would be a "script way" to create a "multi-choice" hyperlink.

Comment: Now it's possible to have multiple hyperlinks in one cell.