# Remove custom menu from Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I added a menu into my Google Sheets but can't find a way to delete it. The method used to add it was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711379/).

Deleting the script didn't help, and neither did revoking access to my Google account.

What would I do to remove this menu from my menu bar so it no longer shows to the right of the "Help" menu?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method you linked adds a menu when the Spreadsheet is opened. Have you closed the sheet and reopened it since deleting the `onOpen()` script? (and saving the script)

Without the `onOpen()` function in the bound script the menu will not be added the next time the Spreadsheet is opened.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addMenu(String,Object)

Comment: Yea, it doesn't appear to be there anymore, though I did close it and reopen it before posting this. I guess maybe it was cached for me or something along those lines.