# How to extract the link from a cell now that links are not reflected as HYPERLINK?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

"Insert Link" is not producing a `=HYPERLINK(’’,’’)` anymore.

Before, if you linked a cell with a value ‘X’. It was converted into the formula `=HYPERLINK(*link*,’X’)`

Two days ago "Insert Link" changed.

Now the content of the cell remains the same, it is just underlined.

Using a script, how can I extract the link from a Cell now that neither its value nor its formula contains this information?

I searched the documentation but the only method related to links that I was able to find was `setShowHyperlink(showHyperlink)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I could confirm your situation. In this case, it seems that the hyperlink can be retrieved from `RichTextValue` object. Namely, I thought that the specification was changed to that the hyperlink is given to the text using `RichTextValue`.

So as a sample case, it supposes as follows.

- A text of `X` is put in a cell "A1".
- This cell is manually linked to a URL like `https://www.google.com`.

In this case, the cell has no `=HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com","X")`. The sample script for retrieving the URL from this situation is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var url = sheet.getRange("A1").getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl();
console.log(url);
```

- In this case, the URL is linked to whole text in a URL. So above script can be used.

#### Note:

- In the current stage, the multiple hyperlinks can be added to the texts in one cell. For example, when 2 URLs are put to the text in a cell, you can use the following sample script. In this sample, a text of `url1, url2` is put to a cell "A1", and `url1` and `url2` are linked with each link.

  ```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var RichTextValue = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
    .setText("url1, url2")
    .setLinkUrl(0, 4, "https://url1/")
    .setLinkUrl(6, 10, "https://url2/")
    .build();
  sheet.getRange("A1").setRichTextValue(RichTextValue);
  ```
- When the multiple URLs are retrieved from the text in a cell, you can use the following sample script.

  ```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1");
  var RichTextValue = range.getRichTextValue().getRuns();
  var res = RichTextValue.reduce((ar, e) => {
    var url = e.getLinkUrl();
    if (url) ar.push(url);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  console.log(res);
  ```

#### References:

- [getRichTextValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrichtextvalue)
- [getRichTextValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrichtextvalues)
- [Class RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value)

### Updated at June 13, 2020:

By the update at [June 12, 2020](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/), the documents of [`getLinkUrl()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value#getlinkurl) and [`setLinkUrl(linkUrl)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder#setlinkurllinkurl) were added to the official documents.

Comment: Where did you find `getLinkUrl()`?

Comment: @TheMaster I used `getLinkUrl()` with the auto completion of the script editor. But now, I could notice that when I look for the official document of `getLinkUrl()` now, it is not included. I'm surprised for this. It seems that that the official document is not updated yet. But I believe that the official document will be updated in the near future.

Comment: @TheMaster I could confirm that by the update at [June 12, 2020](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/), the documents of [`getLinkUrl()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value#getlinkurl) and [`setLinkUrl(linkUrl)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder#setlinkurllinkurl) were added to the official documents.

Comment: @Tanaike   var url = e.getLinkUrl();
  if (url) ar.push(url);   we are able to get the URL, but is there any way we can find out the text where the link is applied along with these urls?

Comment: @Sanat What do you think `e` is?

Comment: its a subString, Thanks I got the text actually  :)