# Multiple links in once cell using Google Sheets API

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm writing a simple python script to automatically fill data in the spreadsheet and need to set multiple link in one cell. How can this be done via Sheets API?
This feature has been added recently to the Sheets UI, but I cannot find anything in the API documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that the multiple URLs cannot be set to a cell using Sheets API. But Sheets API is growing now. So I believe that the method for achieving this will be added in the future update. At that time, I think that it might add to TextFormatRun. So I think that as a current workaround, how about using Web Apps as an API? The sample script can be seen at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61788303/7108653 If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.