# How to fetch the text from a sentence in a cell on which superscript is present in Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, text, superscript

I have a sentence in a cell in Google Spreadsheet and one of the text in that sentence has a superscript applied. How would I get the information of the text on which superscript is present. Below is an example -

"Rahul is good boy 3" is the sentence in a particular cell in Google spreadsheet and the text "3" is superscripted. How would I get this information that text "3" is superscript

App script is not showing any function which will fetch this information, so would required the help here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract the link from a cell now that links are not reflected as HYPERLINK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61787891/how-to-extract-the-link-from-a-cell-now-that-links-are-not-reflected-as-hyperlin)

Comment: Could you show what you've tried so far? Defend this statement: *App script is not showing any function which will fetch this information*. Also, is the ``3`` superscripted through richtext or just unicode `³`  U+00B3 SUPERSCRIPT THREE?

Comment: @TheMaster He just duplicated his previous question and modified it slightly so it looks "different" to us.

Comment: @Marios More like He used it as a template. Regardless, AFAIK Richtext doesn't provide any superscript information. Technically superscript isn't even rich text. This question is sufficiently different and  the answer there won't apply to this question - I can't close it as duplicate just because the same words are used. Sure, Information is lacking and research effort is lacking as well, but it is not a duplicate. I'm inclined to answer it as well, if OP provides relevant information

Answer (score 0):

Superscripts are just unicodes and fortunately the new v8 Apps script engine supports unicode `/u` flag in regex. You can use [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with appropriate regex to get superscripts. To get all superscript numbers,

```js
//getValue
const val = "Rahul is a good boy³"
const regex = /[\u{2070}\u{2074}-\u{2079}\u{00B9}\u{00B2}-\u{00B3}]/gu;
console.info(val.match(regex))
```

#### References:

- [Unicode property escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes)
- [Unicode superscripts and subscripts](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)
- [String#match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)