# Convert external Hyperlink into Hyperlink formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing an application that involves manipulating cells that have hyperlinks with the `=HYPERLINK("https://...","name")` formula in the cell. Although, my data is copied from an external website and so the links are not written with the hyperlink formula but are still hyperlinks.

**Original**:

[image: Copied and pasted from external website]

**What I want**:

[image: What I want]

Is there any way that I can take in the cell with the original hyperlink and make it so that it is formatted using the hyperlink formula?

Comment: You need VBA to do what you describe. See https://superuser.com/questions/593492/can-i-use-an-excel-formula-to-extract-the-link-location-of-a-hyperlink-in-a-cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to convert from the hyperlink given to a cell to the formula of `HYPERLINK` in the same cell using Google Apps Script.

In this case, the values of URL and cell value can be retrieved with Class RichTextValue. And the retrieved values can be put to the same cell as a formula.

#### Sample script:

Before you test this script, please set the sheet name and cell coordinate of A1Notation.

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";
  const cell = "A1";
  
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange(cell);
  const richText = range.getRichTextValue();
  range.setFormula(`=HYPERLINK("${richText.getLinkUrl()}","${richText.getText()}")`);
}
```

- In this sample script, the cell "A1" is converted.

#### Note:

- Please use this script with enabling V8.
- This sample script is a simple script for explaining the method for achieving your goal. So please modify it for your actual situation.

#### References:

- [Class RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value)
- [setFormula(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormula(String))
- Related question

  - [How to extract the link from a cell now that links are not reflected as HYPERLINK?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61787891/7108653)

Comment: holy it's that simple I don't know why an hour of searching couldn't find me this script. tyty

Comment: @Timothy Oh Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: @tanaike this is great thank you. Any chance you can make this function a custom formula? for example =converturl(range) ?

Comment: @Mel Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, the custom function cannot put the formula. It seems that this is the current specification. I apologize for this.