# Get hyperlink from Google Sheet cell using PHP API

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have found other related articles, but none give me the answers I need based on the PHP API.

I have a spreadsheet with cells that include hyperlinks:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
$get_range = "Sheet1!A:Z";
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $get_range, ['valueRenderOption' => 'FORMULA']);
$values = $response->getValues();
```

Here's what `$values` returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Column Title
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Some Item
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Some Item with a Link
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Some Item
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Another Item
        )
)
```

You'll notice that there's nothing related to the link in the returned data. Has anyone had any success getting the link using the PHP API?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to retrieve the hyperlinks from a sheet in Google Spreadsheet using googleapis for php.
- A hyperlink is put to a cell.
- You have already been able to retrieve values from Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, it is required to use the method of "spreadsheets.get" in Sheets API. And also, it is required to use `fields` for this.

When above points are reflected to a sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
$spreadsheetId = "###"; // please set Spreadsheet ID.
$sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set sheet name.

$res = $service->spreadsheets->get($spreadsheetId, ["ranges" => [$sheetName], "fields" => "sheets(data(rowData(values(hyperlink,formattedValue))))"]);
$rowData = $res->getSheets()[0]->getData()[0]->getRowData();
$result = [];
foreach ($rowData as $i => $row) {
    foreach ($row as $j => $col) {
        $link = $col -> getHyperlink();
        if (isset($link)) {
            array_push($result, ["value" => $col -> getFormattedValue(), "link" => $link, "row" => $i + 1, "col" => $j + 1]);
        }
    }
}
print(json_encode($result));
```

- This sample script supposes that `$service` can be used for retrieving values from Spreadsheet. Please be careful this.
- This sample script retrieves the hyperlinks from a sheet. If you want to retrieve all sheets, please modify above script.
- I used `sheets(data(rowData(values(hyperlink,formattedValue))))` as the value of `fields`. You can also use `sheets` as `fields`.

#### Result:

When above script is run, the following result is obtained.

```
[
  {
    "value": "a3",
    "link": "https://sample1/",
    "row": 3,
    "col": 1
  },
  {
    "value": "a5",
    "link": "https://sample2/",
    "row": 5,
    "col": 1
  }
  ,
  ,
  ,
]
```

- `value` and `link` are the cell value and the hyperlink of the cell, respectively.
- `row` and `col` are the the row number and column number of the cell, respectively.

#### Note:

- In this sample script, it supposes that the cell has the hyperlink. If the hyperlink is the word in the text in a cell, in the current stage, the hyperlink cannot be retrieved. If you want to retrieve it, it is required to use Google Apps Script as a current workaround. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61787891/7108653)

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

### Added:

From your shared Spreadsheet, I understood that you wanted to retrieve the cell value and hyperlink from a cell and put them to each cell. For this, I think that by modifying above sample script, your goal can be achieved. The modified script is as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
$spreadsheetId = "###"; // please set Spreadsheet ID.
$sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set sheet name.

$res = $service->spreadsheets->get($spreadsheetId, ["ranges" => [$sheetName], "fields" => "sheets(data(rowData(values(hyperlink,formattedValue))))"]);
$rowData = $res->getSheets()[0]->getData()[0]->getRowData();
$result = [];
foreach ($rowData as $i => $row) {
    foreach ($row as $j => $col) {
        $link = $col -> getHyperlink();
        if (isset($link)) {
            array_push($values, [$col -> getFormattedValue(), $link]);
        }
    }
}
$range = "Sheet2";
$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(array('values' => $values));
$service->spreadsheets_values->update($spreadsheetId, $range, $body, array('valueInputOption' => 'USER_ENTERED'));
```

- In this script, the cell values and hyperlinks retrieved from "Sheet1" are put to "Sheet2" by splitting the cell values and hyperlinks. So before you use this script, please add the sheet of "Sheet2".
- In this case, the values are put to the Spreadsheet. So please be careful the scopes you are using.

Comment: You mentioned this in your code:
`sheets(data(rowData(values(hyperlink,formattedValue))))`

Is that literal or are those supposed to be defined variables?

Comment: @Loko Web Design Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `sheets(data(rowData(values(hyperlink,formattedValue))))`, this is the value of `fields` which is the string value. Using `fields`, the specific values can be retrieved from Google APIs. For example, you can see the fields of `sheets` at [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets). But if my answer was not useful for your question, I apologize.

Comment: @Loko Web Design Is there anything that I can do for your question? If my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. I would like to think of about the solution.

Comment: Sorry for not replying. I wasn't able to get your code to work. I ended up just adding a column for links and pulling from there instead of trying to get the embedded links.

Comment: @Loko Web Design Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I ended up just adding a column for links and pulling from there instead of trying to get the embedded links.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? By this, I would like to try to understand it. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: Instead of having a cell with a value that includes a link, I just created 2 cells: one with the text and the other with a URL. Then I pulled those into my PHP.

Comment: @Loko Web Design Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `Instead of having a cell with a value that includes a link, I just created 2 cells: one with the text and the other with a URL. Then I pulled those into my PHP.`. Can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the input and output you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: See https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pQ6ZmrNzxjBqsPYiwiYx0B9MkilOEDA7ULyJQ9MzZTA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Loko Web Design Thank you for replying. From your shared Spreadsheet, I added one more sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize again.