# How to retrieve url from a hyperlinked value resulted from a formula?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet that is processing data, and there is a column where the formula outputs values that are hyperlinked. I tried many of the methodologies shares here and in Google, but I don't see a way to extract the url with a custom formula in these cases.

Here's a spreadsheet example, and I need to extract the url from cell E2 in F2 for example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xOOEEBTQ2qyTpBrwM6YAzht7zPZw0Xl2WfJvJ7rRD70/edit?usp=sharing

Does anyone have a custom function to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't  you use getFormula and treat is as a string and remove the url with slice or substring or perhaps some regex method?

Answer (score 1):

I found this script answer on another site:

```
function GETLINK(input){
return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(input).getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl()
}
```

I can't see a way to do it with just a formula.

### Update

[This previous question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61787891/how-to-extract-the-link-from-a-cell-now-that-links-are-not-reflected-as-hyperlin) has a more detailed solution, to handle multiple URLs in a cell.

[image]

Comment: thanks @kirkg13 for the suggestion. I actually did try that option haha. The problem is that because the hyperlinked output (E2) is the result of a formula, that function won't work (it does work with the cell where the link is). So this won't solve it for my purpose.

Comment: I implemented your options to try, but I get the error "Range not found (line 2).
". How did you implement the script that it did work for you given the screenshot? can make the change in the spreadsheet? Thanks!