# How do I get/create a hyperlink in only part of a cell?

Tags: java, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to figure how to get or create a hyperlink in only part of a Google Spreadsheets cell. For example, if my cell was written in markdown, it would look like this:

```
Device ID, found on [the inventory website](https://www.example.com/)
```

I tried the methods `CellFormat#getHyperlinkDisplayType()` and `CellData#getHyperlink()`, both of which returned null. I examined all the cell data in my debugger, and did not see the URL present anywhere. This gives me reason to believe that I need include another field in the `setFields` method:

```
Sheets sheets = auth.getService();
Get request = sheets.spreadsheets().get(id).setFields(
"sheets.properties,sheets.data.rowData.values(effectiveValue,effectiveFormat.backgroundColor)");
Spreadsheet response = request.execute();
```

I am not sure which field would include the hyperlink, nor can I find a list of the fields available to me. I was also wishing to be able to *create* a hyperlink which only covers part of the text in a cell.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve or create a hyperlink in a part of text in a cell using Sheets API.
- As a sample situation, you want to retrieve `https://www.example.com/` from the cell "B1" of the following situation of Spreadsheet. And also, you want to create the situation like the cell "B1".

  | Row | Column A | Column B |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | 1 | Device ID | found on [the inventory website](https://www.example.com/) |

### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are not methods for retrieving and creating a hyperlink in a part of text in a cell using Sheets API. So in this answer, I would like to propose a workaround to achieve your goal.
In this workaround, the Web Apps created by Google Apps Script is used as the wrapper. Because when Spreadsheet service of Google Apps Script is used, your goal can be directly achieved. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61787891) The Web Apps is used like an API. So the flow of this workaround is as follows.

1. At client side, request to the Web Apps.
2. At Web Apps side, retrieve and create the hyperlink in a part of text in a cell using Google Apps Script.
3. Return the result to the client side.

In order to use this workaround, please do the following flow.

### Usage:

#### 1. Create new project of Google Apps Script.

Sample script of Web Apps is a Google Apps Script. So please create a project of Google Apps Script.

If you want to directly create it, please access to https://script.new/. In this case, if you are not logged in Google, the log in screen is opened. So please log in to Google. By this, the script editor of Google Apps Script is opened.

#### 2. Prepare Web Apps side. (server side)

Please copy and paste the following script (Google Apps Script) to the script editor and save the project. This script is for the Web Apps. This Web Apps is used as an API.

```
// This function is used for retrieving the hyperlinks from a sheet in a Google Spreadsheet.
function doGet(e) {
  let returnValue = "";
  const {method, spreadsheetId, sheetName} = e.parameter;
  if (method == "get") {
    const res = getHyperlinks(spreadsheetId, sheetName);
    returnValue = JSON.stringify(res);
  } else {
    returnValue = "Error: No method.";
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(returnValue);
}

// This function is used for creating a cell including the hyperlinks in a part of cell text on a sheet in a Google Spreadsheet.
function doPost(e) {
  let returnValue = "";
  const {method, spreadsheetId, sheetName} = e.parameter;
  if (method == "create") {
    if (e.postData) {
      const res = createHypetlinks(spreadsheetId, sheetName, JSON.parse(e.postData.contents));
      returnValue = JSON.stringify(res);
    } else {
      returnValue = "Error: No object for creating hyperlink in a cell.";
    }
  } else {
    returnValue = "Error: No method.";
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(returnValue);
}

function createHypetlinks(spreadsheetId, sheetName, object) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange(object.rowIndex + 1, object.columnIndex + 1);
  const builder = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(object.cellText);
  object.hyperlinks.forEach(({startIndex, endIndex, url}) => builder.setLinkUrl(startIndex, endIndex, url));
  range.setRichTextValue(builder.build());
  return "Done.";
}

function getHyperlinks(spreadsheetId, sheetName) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const richTextValues = sheet.getDataRange().getRichTextValues();
  const hyperlinks = richTextValues.reduce((ar, r, i) => {
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      const temp = c.getRuns().reduce((arr, r) => {
        const link = r.getLinkUrl();
        if (link) {
          arr.push({text: r.getText(), hyperlink: link});
        }
        return arr;
      }, []);
      if (temp.length > 0) {
        ar.push({rowIndex: i, columnIndex: j, hyperlinks: temp});
      }
    });
    return ar;
  }, []);
  return hyperlinks;
}
```

#### 3. Deploy Web Apps.

The detail information can be seen at [the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app).

1. On the script editor, at the top right of the script editor, please click "click Deploy" -> "New deployment".
2. Please click "Select type" -> "Web App".
3. Please input the information about the Web App in the fields under "Deployment configuration".
4. Please select **"Me"** for **"Execute as"**.

   - This is the important of this workaround.
5. Please select **"Anyone"** for **"Who has access"**.

   - In this case, the user is not required to use the access token. So please use this as a test case.
   - When you want to use the access token, please set it to `Anyone with Google account` or `Only myself`. By this, the user can access to the Web Apps using the access token. When you use the access token, please include the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`.
6. Please click "Deploy" button.
7. When "The Web App requires you to authorize access to your data" is shown, please click "Authorize access".
8. Automatically open a dialog box of "Authorization required".

   1. Select own account.
   2. Click "Advanced" at "This app isn't verified".
   3. Click "Go to ### project name ###(unsafe)"
   4. Click "Allow" button.
9. Copy the URL of Web App. It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`.

   - **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please redeploy as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

#### 3. Testing.

As a simple test, when it requests to the Web Apps using a curl command, it becomes as follows. Please set your Web Apps URL, the method, spreadsheet ID and sheet name, and also, the request body. When the Web Apps is correctly deployed, the values are returned.

Retrieve hyperlinks from a sheet.

```
$ curl -L 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?method=get&spreadsheetId={your Spreadsheet ID}&sheetName=Sheet1'
```

- The start index of `rowIndex` and `columnIndex` is `0`. So for example, `rowIndex: 1` and `columnIndex: 1` is the cell "B2";
- When your Web Apps is correctly deployed and your curl command is correct and the spreadsheet has the sample of top table, the following result is obtained.

  ```
    [
      {
        "rowIndex":0,
        "columnIndex":1,
        "hyperlinks":[{"text":"the inventory website","hyperlink":"https://www.example.com/"}]
      }
    ]
  ```

Create a cell including hyperlinks.

```
$ curl -L -d '{"rowIndex": 0, "columnIndex": 2, "cellText": "found on the inventory website", "hyperlinks": [{"startIndex": 9, "endIndex": 30, "url": "https://www.example.com/"}]}' 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?method=create&spreadsheetId={your Spreadsheet ID}&sheetName=Sheet1'
```

- The start index of `startIndex` and `endIndex` is `0`. So for example, when the cell text is `sample text` and you want to give the link to `text`, `startIndex` and `endIndex` is `7` and `11`, respectively;
- When above sample curl command is run, `found on the inventory website` is put to the cell "C1" and `the inventory website` has the hyperlink of `https://www.example.com/` as follows. And, you can see `Done.` at the console.

  [image]

### Note:

- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)
- [Class RichTextValueBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder)
- Related thread

  - [How to extract the link from a cell now that links are not reflected as HYPERLINK?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61787891)