# Google Sheets script function -- make cell contents ALL CAPS unless the cell contains a hyperlink

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the following function to change the contents of column 1 and 2 into ALL CAPS upon edit. This works well.

I would like it modified to skip the function if the contents of that cell is a hyperlink. Column 1 or 2 may occasionally contain a link to a folder and do not want to modify the contents of that cell if there is a link associated with it.

Am I able to use the ISURL() function somehow?

Any advice appreciated.

```
onEdit(e) {AllCaps(e);}

function AllCaps(e) { 
    var sheet, sheetName, colToCapitalize1, colToCapitalize2;
    sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    colToCapitalize1 = 1;
    colToCapitalize2 = 2;
    sheetName = 'Sheet1';
    if (sheet.getName() !== sheetName || e.range.rowStart < 1 || e.range.columnStart > 2 || typeof e.value == 'object') return;
    e.range.setValue(e.value.toUpperCase())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that in your case, in order to check the hyperlink of the edited cell, I would like to propose the following modification. Please modify your script as follows.

#### From:

```
if (sheet.getName() !== sheetName || e.range.rowStart < 1 || e.range.columnStart > 2 || typeof e.value == 'object') return;
```

#### To

```
if (sheet.getName() !== sheetName || e.range.rowStart < 1 || e.range.columnStart > 2 || typeof e.value == 'object' || e.range.getRichTextValue().getRuns().filter(e => e.getLinkUrl()).length > 0) return;
```

- In this modification, `e.range.getRichTextValue().getRuns().filter(e => e.getLinkUrl()).length > 0` is added to the if statement. In this case, when the hyperlinks are included in the edited cell, it returns `true`. By this, `e.range.setValue(e.value.toUpperCase())` is not run.

#### References:

- [getRichTextValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrichtextvalue)
- Related thread

  - [How to extract the link from a cell now that links are not reflected as HYPERLINK?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61787891/7108653)